# Ubuntu writes the number 5 without beeing pressed

Tags: unity, keyboard, firefox, crash, lock-screen

I was looking at the [bitcoin charts](https://www.bitcoin.de/de/chart) and when selecting 3 Years firefox stopped working for a short time and when it continued to work it wrote many 5 in the top bar like when you hold the key.

Ubuntu or more percisely has to be the cause of this problem because I have Kubuntu and Windows installed too and on them I've never had such problems.

This also happened to me when I left my pc alone. When I returned I saw that there were many letters in the password field.

Now it happened again but I can't say how. I was just surfing Ask Ubuntu and looked at steam for a download.

And again just a few minutes later when I was just on Aks Ubuntu and looked for a solution for my question it happened again.

Is this a software issue and if yes how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an external keyboard? If so you might try disconnecting it and using the on screen keyboard (onboard) for awhile and see if it happens. When you say "password field", do you mean the login screen? Also disable your network to eliminate any possibility of remote monkey business.

Comment: @user3169 Yes but I mean the one when your pc locks after a while of inactivity. Well I think it can't be a hardware problem because I have Kubuntu and Windows installed too and there I have no problems.

Comment: So this only happens when locked, and not in any normal screen or app?

Comment: @user3169 this happens in lock screen (Is this lightDM?) and in Firefox.

Comment: In Firefox, what characters are displayed? In the URL bar or in a form?

Comment: @user3169 It is like if I press and holded the key 5. That means it writes everywhere where I click.

Comment: Happens to me too (like number 5 is pressed)... I have an external keyboard Logitech K520. I tried changing the nano receiver but it made no difference. I don't use Windows much so I can't say for sure if it's an ubuntu problem... Some days this happens frequently and other days it will work fine.
When it happens on the lock screen, the screen will hang for a couple of minutes because of the amount of characters... It's super annoying...

Comment: More people with the same problem... Seems other Linux distros are affected too: http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboards-and-Keyboard-Mice/Ubuntu-15-10-and-K520-key-5-automatically-pressed-resulting-in/td-p/1488639

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is probably not the cause (unless you misconfigured the keyboard layout, however do to auto setup it's highly unlikely) most likely that key is broken. See about going to a local repair shop. If your worried you can always remove the hard drive before giving them the computer.

Comment: Thank you for your advise but ubuntu has to be the cause because I have Kubuntu and Windows installed too and I've never had such problems.

Comment: First you mentioned "many 5", then later "letters in the password field". If different keys are involved, it is not likely to be a physical key problem. You might clarify that in your question.

Comment: @user3169 I assume they are 5's but can't be sure because in the password field there are only `*` displayed.